# String to Date and Time formate and date and time to string in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, ios5, object, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I tried to convert String to date time and date time to string it's working but some what error. I not getting correct formate.
**my excepting result should be:**
 like this.02/02/2013 05:24PM 
time should be 12 hours formate;

```
 NSString *dateTime = @"2013-02-02 15:54:31";
    int time=[[temp objectForKey:@"created"]intValue];
     NSLog(@"Time=%d",time);

    // Convert string to date object
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
        [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:dateTime]];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateTime];
        NSLog(@"Nsdate=%@",date);

        // Convert date object to desired output format
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
        dateTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
        [dateFormat release];
        NSLog(@"DateTime=%@",dateTime);

    --------------------
    NSLogs :

     Time=2013
     DateTime=2013-02-02 17:06:09
     Nsdate=2013-01-02 11:30:00 +0000//it's not correct date
     DateTime=02/01/2013 05:00PM//it's not correct date and time// 
   ------------- 
    my excepting result should be like this:

    DateTime :02/02/2013 05:24PM
```

If you have any idea please shear your ideas , It's will help me.

Comment: I strongly recommend you **read** the **documentation** of `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your this line

```
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
```

to

```
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:SS"];
```

mm and dd should be small

Hope it helps you..

Comment: it working for Time only  not date....date should be 02/02/2013 but it showing 02/01/2013 or 02/06/2013 'Nsdate=2013-01-02 11:36:00 +0000
DateTime=02/06/2013 05:06PM                                               // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mma"];'

Comment: I tried this nslog: 02/01/2013 06:27PM but month should be 02..i am not getting correct date formate..

Comment: Can you paste your entire code again, in your question how can DateTime be printed before Nsdate. Paste your entire code, don't leave anything..

Comment: check the timezone of the NSDateFormatter. The value of dateTime is not a timezone name.

Comment: My code: 'NSString *dateTime = @"2013-02-02 15:54:31";
    
    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:dateTime]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateTime];
    
    
    NSLog(@"Nsdate=%@",date);
    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma"];
    dateTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormat release];  '

Comment: Ok, here is code for you  NSString *dateTime = @"2013-02-02 15:54:31"; // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    //[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:dateTime]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateTime];
    NSLog(@"Nsdate=%@",date); // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mma"];
    dateTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"DateTime : %@",dateTime);
    [dateFormat release];

Comment: This line was causing issue [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:dateTime]];

Comment: out put:DateTime=2013-02-02 15:54:31;Nsdate=2013-01-02 10:24:31 +0000;Date Time=02/01/2013 03:54PM

Comment: I have tried my above code, and it shows proper result, have you copied entire code. if yes paste your code again..

Comment: I deleted settimezone methos also..no change in my result.         I think this line  not getting correct date from string ..  NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateTime]; date out put :Nsdate=2013-01-02 10:24:31 +0000, here year and date are correct but month was 01 but it's should be 02.. for get correct month I need to included any NSDate default methods here??

Comment: Hi brother it's working ,, I am very happy thank for your knowledge .. and you.